# New Server & SQL Installation - VBScript agent job takes 6 times longer

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, agent

We have a non-production environment server to migrate all our data from our main databases to a new server.

We are migrating from:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5520.0 (Intel X86)  Jul 11 2014
>   12:30:03  Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation Standard
>   Edition on Windows NT 5.2  (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

To:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)  Mar 19 2015
>   12:32:14  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Our biggest problem so far is that we have a database in the IBM AIX environment which we need to dump daily databases then individual databases every 20 minutes.  On the current production server, this works absolutely fine, but on the new configuration (non-production) it's taking 6 times longer, in fact 2 hours!

I'm just not sure where to start looking for such a cause.

It's scripted via VBScript as it requires an array of tables to be copied from the AIX environment to SQL.  We know of no other way of accessing the data.

We managed to address a driver issue between x86 and x64 but prior to this, we managed to run a .VBS file using CScript in the appropriate flavour to ensure the x64 driver didn't cause an issue.  This also took 2 hours, which is why we managed to trial the correct driver, but is still taking just as long.

It's an odd one and could be open to many issues, but any advice would be gratefully accepted!

```
arrTableList = Array ("array","of","tables")
sSQLConn = "DSN=[New SQL Server]; UID=[username];PWD=[password];DATABASE=[DBName];"
sUniplanConn = "DSN=[USQL Database].udd;"

Const adCmdText = &H1
Const adUseClient = 3
Const adCmdStoredProc = &H4
Const adParamInput = &H1
Const adChar = 129
Const adExecuteNoRecords = &H80

Set ConnectConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ConnectConn.Open sSQLConn

Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.ActiveConnection = sUniplanConn

For j = 0 To UBound(arrTableList)
    sTableName = arrTableList(j)

    start = timer()

    sSQL = "select * from " & sTableName 
    rst.source = sSQL
    rst.CursorType = 0
    rst.CursorLocation = 2
    rst.LockType = 3
    rst.Open

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = sSQLConn
    cmd.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

    sSQL = "EXEC ADODBRecordsetImport 1"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

    For Each Field In rst.Fields
        'Debug.Print Field.Type & vbTab & Field.DefinedSize & vbTab & Field.Name
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO Temp_Recordset_Schema " _
                & "SELECT '" & sTableName & "_Import','" & Field.Name & "','" & Field.Type & "','" & Field.DefinedSize & "'"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
    Next

    sSQL = "EXEC ADODBRecordsetImport 2"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords


    sSQL = "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords


    Do Until rst.EOF
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sTableName & "_Import VALUES("
        For n = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
            sFieldValue = rst(n)
            'Debug.Print rst(n) & vbTab & rst(n).Type

            If IsNull(rst(n)) Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "Null,"
            Else
                If rst(n).Type = 133 Then sFieldValue = FormatDateTime(sFieldValue, 1)
                sSQL = sSQL & "'" & Replace(sFieldValue, "'", "''") & "',"
            End If
        Next
        sSQL = sSQL & ")"
        sSQL = Replace(sSQL, ",)", ")")
        'Debug.Print sSQL
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    sSQL = "COMMIT"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

    sSQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE " & sTableName
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords



    sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sTableName & " SELECT * FROM " & sTableName & "_Import"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    cmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords

    rst.Close

    start = Timer() - start
    ConnectConn.execute "INSERT INTO Connect.dbo.updatetimes ([Table],[Time]) VALUES ('" & sTableName & "'," & start & ")"
Next

Set cmd = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: 'we have a database in the IBM AIX environment' -- any details regarding that database?

Comment: Apologies, we use U/SQL (Transoft) and we connect to that via an ODBC connection

Comment: Can you show the vbscript code?  Don't forget to mask out anything that's confidential (i.e. don't post any passwords etc!)

Comment: @Dave I've added the VBS code to my original post.  Bearing in mind this works fine on our current server (takes 20 minutes), but running the same code, takes 2 hours!

Comment: Hmmm, if the same script takes 20 minutes on one system and 2 hours on the other I'd be inclined to blame the config rather than any scripting (for example, does the new machine have a slower network connection?)

Comment: Network is set at 10gb, I've found an issue I wasn't aware of and currently dealing with; one of the tables holds 3.4 million results!  Each time, the table is truncated and rebuilt!  It still only takes 20 minutes on the current server but this has highlighted an issue and I've re-organised it to import the data differently.